# Multi-file archive format supporting iteration in python

Tags: python, iteration, compression, archive

I recently realized that neither `.tar.gz` nor `.zip` archive file enable quick iteration over the files they contain in python. Let me elaborate.

I have a large collection of files. The statistics are the following:

- Number of files: 4'810'289
- Number of directories: 402'212
- The `tar.gz` archive is 9GB.
- The `.zip` archive file is 16GB.
- Uncompressed data weighs 190GB.

Using the `.tar.gz` method, I thought I could create an index by pickling the result of the following code:

```
with tarfile.open(self.file.path, "r:gz") as tar:
    return tar.getmembers()
```

The result is a pickle file of about 2GB, but the problem is that you have to read the whole archive in full for every member you want to extract. Indeed, running `tar.extractfile(member)` afterwards takes a few minutes for every member! So no go here.

Using the `.zip` method is slightly different, but still doesn't enable quick iteration on files. As soon as you execute:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
zip = ZipFile(file_path)
```

The module seems to load a the full file into RAM, as the interpreter hangs for about 5 minutes and ends up using 19GB of RAM (looking at `top`) for as long as you keep the `zip` object around. Afterwards `zip.infolist()` and `zip.open(member).read()` are very fast. So at least it's better than `.tar.gz`.

Is there anyway to have a multi-file compressed archive format in python that is able to iterate on files one after another without having to load the full file, build a lengthy index or having to read the whole file every time?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question could be better suited for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ site, since you seem to be looking for a library/package.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Currently 3.10, but a solution for 3.11 is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing that `ZipFile` behavior. This is on a 16 GB zip file with about 11,000 entries. The memory usage is nowhere near the size of the zip file:

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Sep 26 2022, 11:37:49) 
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tracemalloc
>>> tracemalloc.start()
>>> print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
(8797, 11854)
>>> from zipfile import ZipFile
>>> print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
(1429688, 1448932)
>>> zip = ZipFile("/Users/madler/Downloads/iCloud Photos Part 12 of 12.zip")
>>> print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
(9208481, 10508727)
>>> info = zip.infolist()
>>> len(info)
11341
>>> print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
(9210488, 10508727)
```

All of the commands executed instantly, as far as I could tell.

I would expect the memory usage to be proportional to the number of entries in the zip file, not to the zip file size. `ZipFile` should just be reading the zip file's central directory into memory. I am seeing on the order of 700 bytes of memory per entry in my example. Extrapolating, that would be about 3 GB for yours, if the files names are of comparable length. That's a good chunk of memory, but certainly not 19 GB.

Comment: I ran the same commands, only changing the path to the zip file, and the result is: `(11395904654, 13482663202)` after ~5 minutes. It just seems that reading the first file at the top of the archive should not require any loading of anything.

Comment: To read one file from a zip file requires, at a minmum, finding the end of central directory record at the end of the zip file, using the offset in that to find the start of the central directory, which is after all of the entries in the zip file and before the end of central directory record, and using the first entry in the central directory to get the offset of the first entry in the zip (usually at the start), and extracting it from there.

Comment: You don't have to load the entire central directory into memory, but that is a convenient thing to do for randomly accessing files in a zip file, and is what the Python library is doing. That seems sensible to me, but it appears to be rather taxing for your particular zip file.

Comment: I don't know why your memory usage is as high as it is. Perhaps the file names in the your zip file are unusually long. As for the several minutes it is taking to load the central directory, I wonder if your machine is thrashing. How much memory does it have?

Comment: It's a standard VPS with 10 cores and 58GB. Filenames are between 20 and 40 characters. I guess I was just wondering if there are other file archive formats that wouldn't require going to the end of the file to get a central index.

Comment: I think in the end I'm just going to sub-sample the zip file and build a smaller test-case file for development.

Comment: The average name length in mine is 58 characters. It seems odd that I'm seeing 700 bytes of memory per entry, whereas you're seeing 2400 bytes per entry. Does your 20 to 40 characters include the path for each entry?

Comment: All of the archive formats have a central directory of some sort. However you don't have to read the whole thing in. You could write your own zip file processing that just searches the central directory for each access, and not use hardly any memory at all. Or you could scan the central directory and save just a list of offsets to each central directory entry for rapid access. Only 40 MB in your case.

Comment: Yes, the list of offsets would be what is needed here. It's a pity that the python zip library doesn't provide that, and there to be no other library or compression format that does. Unfortunately, this project doesn't have the ressources to start adding such functionality to the bulit-in library.